# iptables, Apache2 and cgi

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iptables, port-forwarding, cgi

I'm running Perl cgi script providing some reports on Apache webserver on a host behind DSL modem doing port forwarding. Overview:

```
net <-> DSL_Modem (192.168.1.254) <-> Ap2host (eth1/192.168.1.222, eth0/10.0.0.1)
```

DSL modem port-forwards public port `30016` to the Apache2 host, namely `192.168.1.222:30016`.

Opening the script webpage from the private network (`10.0.0.0/8`, provided by Apache2 host via `eth0`) works fine.

Now, the weird thing is that if I set up forwarding this way:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.222 --dport 30016 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p tcp --dst 10.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:30016
/sbin/iptables -I genfilter 1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30016 -j ACCEPT
```

...browser displays contents of Perl script when the url is opened from the internet (URL like http://example.com:30016).

But if I do this instead:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.222 --dport 30050 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
/sbin/iptables -I genfilter 1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30050 -j ACCEPT
```

..browser opens a generated page correctly (again from the internet of course).

Why should `-j REDIRECT` work while `DNAT/SNAT` port forwarding be a problem? This (`DNAT/SNAT`) way of port forwarding works just fine for me for other services, e.g. port-forwarding `RDP`.

Comment: did you added +ExecCGI to your apache options ?

Comment: @Froggiz Yes I did, and as I wrote, when the webpage is opened from internal network (and using -j REDIRECT), it works just fine, i.e. it shows generated page instead of script contents.